# See extension method calls by derived class in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have an extension method on oPersistentObject which is a base class of a lot of different objects.

Now I want to see where that method is called but only for MaintenanceGroups ( or any other derived class ).

I can't see any easy way to do this.

Original method signature:

```
public static void PersistThrowOnFailure( oPersistentObject persistent, ErrorDetector ed = null )
```

The only way I've figured it out:

```
  public static void PersistThrowOnFailure( this ObjectPartGroup persistent, ErrorDetector ed = null ) => GenericPersistThrowOnFailure( persistent, ed );
  public static void PersistThrowOnFailure( this Site persistent, ErrorDetector ed = null ) => GenericPersistThrowOnFailure( persistent, ed );
  public static void PersistThrowOnFailure( this InteroperabilityAssetSettings persistent, ErrorDetector ed = null ) => GenericPersistThrowOnFailure( persistent, ed );

  public static void GenericPersistThrowOnFailure( oPersistentObject persistent, ErrorDetector ed = null )
```

This works but is tedious.  But it is nice that I can see how many times the method is called for each derived type.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to see that nethod is called or update all calls for derived classes? What is the `MaintenanceGroups`?

Comment: I just want to see where it is called for each derived class.  If you look at the example screenshot it shows how many times it is called for Site, ObjectPartGroup, and InteroperabilityAssetSettings.  MaintenanceGroup is just another derived class.